# how to find if a td of table exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to set a condition in javascript "If a table `<td>` exists then show its cells counts, else alert("No TD exist")". My table is like this

```html
<table id="tableid" class="cf7-db-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th title="Submitted">
        <div id="PC form,Submitted">Submitted</div>
      </th>
      <th title="cmName">
        <div id="PC form,cmName">cmName</div>
      </th>
      <th title="cCNumber">
        <div id="PC form,cCnicNumber">cCNumber</div>
      </th>
      <th title="cMEmail">
        <div id="PC form,cMEmail">cMEmail</div>
      </th>
      <th title="cAcNumber">
        <div id="PC form,cAcNumber">cAcNumber</div>
      </th>
      <th title="refNumber">
        <div id="PC form,refNumber">refNumber</div>
      </th>
      <th title="pDate">
        <div id="PC form,prcDate">pDate</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid; you have an extra `</th>`

Comment: Do you mean like `let cellCount = document.querySelectorAll('#tableid td').length`?

Comment: Sorry i removed it

Comment: If a table <td> exists then show its cells counts, else alert("No TD exist")

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your example table does not show any Table Body data. What is populating the table? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `querySelectorAll` you can access the DOM and check for the `td` elements inside the table.

The example below show a case like the one you provided that contains no `td` elements and another that does:

```js
const tableHasTd = selector => {
  /*
   * The querySelectorAll is used to get the elements 
   * in the provided selector. Only length is used to
   * check is any is found.
   */ 
  const { length } = document.querySelectorAll(selector)
  console.log(`Found ${length} td elements in the table`)
  return Boolean(length > 0)
}

tableHasTd('#tableid td')
const isTD = tableHasTd('#table-withtd td')

// the return value of the funciton can be used as condition
if (isTD) {
  console.log('This table has td')
}

tableHasTd('#no-table td')
```

```html
<h2>Table without td</h2>
<table id="tableid" class="cf7-db-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th title="Submitted">
        <div id="PC form,Submitted">Submitted</div>
      </th>
      <th title="cmName">
        <div id="PC form,cmName">cmName</div>
      </th>
      <th title="cCNumber">
        <div id="PC form,cCnicNumber">cCNumber</div>
      </th>
      <th title="cMEmail">
        <div id="PC form,cMEmail">cMEmail</div>
      </th>
      <th title="cAcNumber">
        <div id="PC form,cAcNumber">cAcNumber</div>
      </th>
      <th title="refNumber">
        <div id="PC form,refNumber">refNumber</div>
      </th>
      <th title="pDate">
        <div id="PC form,prcDate">pDate</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<h2>Table with td</h2>
<table id="table-withtd" class="cf7-db-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th title="Submitted">
        <div id="PC form,Submitted">Submitted</div>
      </th>
      <th title="cmName">
        <div id="PC form,cmName">cmName</div>
      </th>
      <th title="cCNumber">
        <div id="PC form,cCnicNumber">cCNumber</div>
      </th>
      <th title="cMEmail">
        <div id="PC form,cMEmail">cMEmail</div>
      </th>
      <th title="cAcNumber">
        <div id="PC form,cAcNumber">cAcNumber</div>
      </th>
      <th title="refNumber">
        <div id="PC form,refNumber">refNumber</div>
      </th>
      <th title="pDate">
        <div id="PC form,prcDate">pDate</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>31</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Review the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  function countCells(tObj) {
    return $("td", tObj).length > 0 ? $("td", tObj).length : false;
  }

  function addRow(tObj) {
    $("<tr>").appendTo($("tbody", tObj));
    $("th", tObj).each(function() {
      $("<td>").html("&nbsp;").appendTo($("tbody tr:last", tObj));
    });
    checkTable(tObj);
  }

  function checkTable(tObj) {
    var count = countCells(tObj);
    if (count) {
      alert("There are " + count + " table cells.");
    } else {
      alert("No Cells Found.");
    }
  }

  checkTable($("#tableid"));

  $("button").click(function() {
    addRow($("#tableid"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableid" class="cf7-db-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th title="Submitted">
        <div id="PC form,Submitted">Submitted</div>
      </th>
      <th title="cmName">
        <div id="PC form,cmName">cmName</div>
      </th>
      <th title="cCNumber">
        <div id="PC form,cCnicNumber">cCNumber</div>
      </th>
      <th title="cMEmail">
        <div id="PC form,cMEmail">cMEmail</div>
      </th>
      <th title="cAcNumber">
        <div id="PC form,cAcNumber">cAcNumber</div>
      </th>
      <th title="refNumber">
        <div id="PC form,refNumber">refNumber</div>
      </th>
      <th title="pDate">
        <div id="PC form,prcDate">pDate</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button>Add Row</button>
```

using a good selector, you can then call `length` on the jQuery object to get a count of the elements selected.

You can also do something like:

```js
$(function() {
  $.fn.countCells = function() {
    return $("td", this).length;
  }

  console.log($("#tableid").countCells());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableid" class="cf7-db-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th title="Submitted">
        <div id="PC form,Submitted">Submitted</div>
      </th>
      <th title="cmName">
        <div id="PC form,cmName">cmName</div>
      </th>
      <th title="cCNumber">
        <div id="PC form,cCnicNumber">cCNumber</div>
      </th>
      <th title="cMEmail">
        <div id="PC form,cMEmail">cMEmail</div>
      </th>
      <th title="cAcNumber">
        <div id="PC form,cAcNumber">cAcNumber</div>
      </th>
      <th title="refNumber">
        <div id="PC form,refNumber">refNumber</div>
      </th>
      <th title="pDate">
        <div id="PC form,prcDate">pDate</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check if table is empty:

```js
console.log($('#tableid').children('tbody').children().length > 0);
```

But also, code for your task:

```js
if($('#tableid').find('td').length > 0){
 console.log('table exist');
}else{
 console.log('table not exist');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableid" class="cf7-db-table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th title="Submitted">
    <div id="PC form,Submitted">Submitted</div>
   </th>
   <th title="cmName">
    <div id="PC form,cmName">cmName</div>
   </th>
   <th title="cCNumber">
    <div id="PC form,cCnicNumber">cCNumber</div>
   </th>
   <th title="cMEmail">
    <div id="PC form,cMEmail">cMEmail</div>
   </th>
   <th title="cAcNumber">
    <div id="PC form,cAcNumber">cAcNumber</div>
   </th>
   <th title="refNumber">
    <div id="PC form,refNumber">refNumber</div>
   </th>
   <th title="pDate">
    <div id="PC form,prcDate">pDate</div>
   </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
```